# Creating dynamic objects group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've got the following code :

```
function createLineGroup(x, y, hLine, wLine, wCell, offset) {
    "use strict";

    var i,
        objects = [],
        group = new fabric.Group();

    for (i = x; i <= (wLine + x); i += (wCell + offset)) {
        group.addWithUpdate(
            new fabric.Rect({
                left: group.get('left') + i,
                width: wCell,
                height: hLine,
                fill: 'red',
                opacity: 0.5
            }));
    }

    group.addWithUpdate(new fabric.Text('test', {
        fontSize: 15,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
    }));

    return group;
}
```

I want to create a group of boxes dynamically and draw them on my canvas. Example :

[image: Example]

Following the width of the cell and the offset it creates the following boxes inside the group.

But it's actually not working, any idea on how to achieve it ?

**Edit 1 :**

Did a JS Fiddle example, this is actually working, but the text is not centered. How to fix it ?

https://jsfiddle.net/dfc40s3u/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some simple math together with the variables you pass into the function.

add this to the `Text` object:

```
left:largeurLigne/2 // the half of the width of all the `Rect` object.
```

Comment: Well, I just did it , it's not exactly centered, but I can't get much more precision, thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: @alexcouter, I was aware about that. It's because you also have some kind on those `Rect` objects. Basically you should try to get the total width of that group of rectangles and than divide it be 2. Now I'm not familiar with FabricJS but you might be able to do something like `left:group.getWidth()/2;`

Comment: I tried many things, and group.width, group.getWidth() gives the same result like the first solution.